# Docker with Apache/PHP/MySQL on Mac - Bad performance

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, containers

I'm currently using a vagrant operated VirtualBox setup to develop my web services. Since I want to move to a new M1 Mac, I need to unfortunately change this setup.

I've now build up a docker environment and for now all works well - except the performance. Especially when running PHPUnit tests, the performance is so bad that it is in fact unusable. A test suite that simply checks if sql statements are valid against the mysql db takes 31.44 seconds on the docker setup while it completes in under 5 seconds on the old setup.

I've read a lot in the last days about the problems with file sharing between container and host, and I've tried some things so far, but in fact nothing changed regarding the performance (not even a bit which really makes me wonder):

- used docker-sync
- changed mysql storage to a named volume
- tried to allocate more CPU / memory

But after 8 hours of trying I'm still seeing the same bad numbers for this test suite, it ranges between 28 and 38 seconds instead of five seconds.

I'm also not really sure what exactly causes the setup being slow - is it the database or PHP itself? Does anybody has an idea on how I could get closer to the actual reason?

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: "mysql"
    build: docker/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/bitnami/mysql/data
      - ./docker/mysql/import:/import:delegated

  php:
    container_name: "php"
    build: docker/php
    volumes:
      - ../App:/app:delegated
      - ./docker/php/ini/php.ini:/opt/bitnami/php/etc/conf.d/php.ini:ro
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal
      - ENVIRONMENT=docker

  apache:
    container_name: "apache"
    image: bitnami/apache:2.4
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ../App:/app:delegated
      - ./docker/apache/my_vhost.conf:/vhosts/my_vhost.conf:ro
      - ./docker/apache/certs:/certs
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal
      - ENVIRONMENT=docker

  # --- PhpMyAdmin latest
  # Acccess via http://127.0.0.1:81 or https://127.0.0.1:8143
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: "phpmyadmin"
    image: bitnami/phpmyadmin:latest
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - '81:8080'
      - '8143:8443'
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal

volumes:
 mysql-data:
    driver: local
```

I would be really happy about all ideas that you could share with me on how to get closer to the reason for this docker setup being that slow. Since our whole test suite now runs over one hour this is absolutely a no-go and would definitely stop me from buying a new M1 mac. But since they're the future I definitely need a long-term solution without virtual machines for developing.

Additional information on request:
I don't have a M1 yet, I'm currently testing on my old system. So I'm comparing docker vs. VirtualBox on the same 2,8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 with 8GB RAM on Mac OS 12.3 Monterey. Docker has 2CPUs and 4GB RAM while (the faster) VirtualBox setup has only 1 CPU and 1GB RAM. So it's worser equipped but faster on the same machine.

MySQL statistics can be found at https://pastebin.com/8pq1aeGR.

Comment: Additional information request, please.  One set from M1 Mac and one set from old setup.
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I don't have a M1 yet, I'm currently testing on my old system. So I'm comparing docker vs. VirtualBox on the same 2,8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 with 8GB RAM on Mac OS 12.3 Monterey. Docker has 2CPUs and 4GB RAM while (the faster) VirtualBox setup has only 1 CPU and 1GB RAM. So it's worser equipped but faster on the same machine. I'll post the SQL results in the next minutes.

Comment: @WilsonHauck here are the results from the new docker setup: https://pastebin.com/8pq1aeGR. Do you also want to see the results from the old setup to compare them? Until now, the server did not had an update from 24 hours, its much less.

Comment: Yes, a set of data from old setup as well to allow comparison.  Preferably after 24 hours of uptime on each.

Comment: The data posted about 3 hours ago on pastebin.com is no longer available.  View profile please for contact info and get in touch.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've now created the analysis data again, hope it will now stay available on pastebin.
Old setup (Vagrant): https://pastebin.com/duK75rMz
New setup (Docker): https://pastebin.com/tebFZeiR
I've also today tested the docker setup on a Linux machine - here the same test suite runs in 10 seconds. So still not as fast as the virtualized Vagrant box, but still 3x faster than Docker on Mac. So I think there are different issues here, not only with MySQL itself...

Comment: @WilsonHauck - I guess we need to steer people away from pastbin !

Comment: It is unfortunate that pastebin.com does NOT identify WHO and WHEN the content has been disabled to avoid the mystery of WHO DID IT!!!.  Quite troubling from my perspective.

Comment: Honesty and integrity are getting a little SHORT!

Comment: @acb1980  Please try posting your data to   justpaste.it  and share the links as an alternative way of sharing your data.

Comment: This is really bad for me too. In my tests, phpunit is also slow for docker and with tests running on SQLITE, with php installed via brew. My configuration is pro m1 8gb. PHP is ok for requests, just in tests it's too slow. My PHP version is 8.1 and yours?
some incompatibility between some modules Maybe PHP 8 and M1?
in my case the PHP8.1 installed is the `arm64` version.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sorry for my late reply, I was out of Office the last days. I've published the information on justpaste.it, https://justpaste.it/6e82z (Docker) and https://justpaste.it/4ab7l (Vagrant). Since these are only test systems and I can only run one at a time, the Uptime is far from 24 hours. I hope that it works this time, if not I'll send you the information via e-mail. Thank you for your help and support so far!

Comment: @acb1980 Progress, Have downloaded data. Analysis in process.  Could we use SKYPE TALK for a few minutes to clarify A) Any SSD or NVME devices involved and B) RAM and CPU's on Vagrant (OLD) and Docker (New) instance.  My Skype ID is  wlhauck@aol.com in Birmingham AL USA. Thanks

Comment: Hello, your "image" has support to platform linux/arm?
I did see some perform different between php compiled to arm and no compiled. 
Check if Architecture": "arm" on your `docker image inspect IMAGENAME`.

I went looking to guarantee the image architecture platform and it has improved a lot here, at least 3x better. Of course it doesn't compare to Linux yet, but it's better.

Comment: Your database is accessible through hostname `mysql`, you don't need to pass the IP to every container

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I'm facing the same issue with multiple servers on both debian and ubuntu images.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist it depends on how you want to see it. In the end I just bought a M1 Mac (which was the original reason to test this) and hoped the best - and in fact on my M1 machine the docker configuration is as fast as the Vagrant configuration on my old machine. So for me buying an M1 Mac solved the problem ;)

Comment: But there's one important note: the above configuration shows Bitnami images which are extremely slow on M1 macs since they're not offering native support for that architecture. I've changed all images to the official images of PHP, MariaDB, Apache, ... and they're running fast on M1 machines.

Answer (score 0):

So, TL;DR for me (which I wanna emphasize is probably not the general solution), was to use nginx.

So, I've been facing a similar issue when using Apache as a reverse proxy, to the point of lost messages and Service 503 errors.

My usage of apache was that I derive Debian:11 image, and install apache and enable my own modules. For some reason, many messages were lost. I'm too used to Apache since I've been using it for over a decade, so... nothing worked after exhausting my options there.

Then I learned nginx and used it as a reverse proxy instead of apache, and all the performance issues were gone. Why? I have not the slightest idea. I'm not exclusively saying this is the ultimate solution, but it's worth it to give it a shot if you're having performance issues.